# What is the median age of magi?

Tags: ars-magica-5, aging

Decrepitude and warping eventually get every magus.  In the section about longevity rituals there is a statement regarding the upper bound:

> Magi of two hundred years or older are rare, but not unheard of.

How long should a magus be expected to live?  What is the median age of death for magi?

Comment: @Ben: [Don't answer in the comments - even partial answers are not allowed in comments.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments) You're welcome to use that as the basis for an answer, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magi should plan to live to 100, suspect they might get to 125, and could specialize and live to 200; although not without significant favor from the SG. Plus or minus how the saga is played; as many saga will end before 50+ years pass.
There is no RAW answer for this in the 5e rules. Very senior magi in the descriptions seem to be 120+ years old. Player magi might be lucky to live past 50.

Sub Rosa (a fan mag for Ars Magica) issue #14 has an article called "Demography of the Order of Hermes" by Mark Shirley which may be useful in answering this question statistically.